# TypeScript function that returns arg with extra property (TS2322)

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I want to implement a function that takes an object with a some known properties and some unknown properties and then returns returns an object with some extra properties added to it:

```js
function addY({ x, ...props}) {
  return {
    x,
    y: x + 1,
    ...props,
  };
}
```

I have tried this:

```js
function addY<T extends { x: number }>({ x, ...props }: T): T & { y: number } {
  return {
    x,
    ...props,
    y: x + 1,
  };
}
```

The error I get is:

> TS2322: Type '{ x: number; } & Omit<T, "x"> & { y: number; }' is not
> assignable to type 'T & { y: number; }'.   Type '{ x: number; } &
> Omit<T, "x"> & { y: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.     '{
> x: number; } & Omit<T, "x"> & { y: number; }' is assignable to the
> constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different
> subtype of constraint '{ x: number; }'

With this I assumed that if the input object has a parameter `y` that is not compatible with a number then the return object would be impossible. So I have tried to mitigate it with:

```js
function addY<T extends { x: number }>({ x, ...props }: T): Omit<T, "y"> & { y: number } {
  return {
    x,
    ...props,
    y: x + 1,
  };
}
```

This gives the error:

> TS2322: Type '{ x: number; } & Omit<T, "x"> & { y: number; }' is not
> assignable to type 'Omit<T, "y"> & { y: number; }'.   Type '{ x:
> number; } & Omit<T, "x"> & { y: number; }' is not assignable to type
> 'Omit<T, "y">'

Comment: Just remove the return type, see what TypeScript says

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković Without a return signature it only works if `y` is not in `props`. If it is, the type of `y` will incorrectly be inferred as the intersection of `typeof props.y` and `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forging object literals with spread syntax and getting the types in line can be tricky in TypeScript. Assuming `x` does not change, you can simplify the problem a bit by not extracting `x` and adding it back to the result, but just destructure `props` separately instead:

```
function addY<T extends { x: number }>(props: T): Omit<T, 'y'> & { y: number } {
  const {x} = props
  return {
    ...props,
    y: x + 1,
  };
}
```

This type checks, and if you define a function `Normalize` to get rid of type aliases

```
type Normalize<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}
```

you can check that the return types are as expected:

```
const o1 = addY({x:10, z: 1})
type TestO1 = Normalize<typeof o1> // {x: number, z: number, y: number}

const o2 = addY({x:10, z: 1, y: 'str'})
type TestO2 = Normalize<typeof o2> // {x: number, z: number, y: number}
```

Of course, you could also use `props.x` instead of destructuring.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoJoB4AqiCmAHlPmKgM6IDeihAXImCALYBG+ATogL4B8AFAAcOcQeQY4AlAwDyzGFFwAaRAHIAnqt6IAZNUTqGTNpx7UAUIkQQE5KNULdEAXkTDR5S4g74oIDkhUXlYAdGHuYkrBBgyEiADUiACMUVbcANzm3ObmUOqC+IgAcnAczMgANjAAXvi42q5UANoA0ogwSADW+OpwwIg4ALoSrYPZ5jZgdohwSS4o6Bj8VPRJAAwq1QxJ3JK5+YU4+HYyc64lZZU1dXkFfTNJ2gD0Tw5GLOwcm+8mXzGMH0440m0zgACZ5mhMMtVhtEFtkipDGo7BxVLt9gUBscoDIIedSuUqrUsLd8Pdwc9Xisfp9vgDfkjaUDzEA)